# React Server Side Rendering and CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to serve css when rendering React components from server side? Currently i have a style tag defined in the head of the parent component. It looks like the following

```
            <style>{"\
            .test-cases{\
            border:2px solid black;\
            margin-left:30px\
            background-color:blue;\
            \
            }\
                .describe{\
                  margin-left:90px;\
                  background-color:yellow;\
                }\
              "}</style>
```

As you can see this can get nasty, as i start applying more css properties. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to server-side at all, but you can use plain javascript object (with camelCase properties) to apply the style:

```
style = {marginLeft: '30px',  backgroundColor: 'blue'}
...

<div style={style}>
...
</div>
```

Then you define your style in a separate file and require it into the main view. Without needing webpack.

Comment: thanks!, just went with defining a separate css file

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using webpack to bundle your files? then you could simply require the css file on your js file, and have it bundled together or separately using plugins

Comment: is there an alternative to webpack, for the moment?

Comment: Use a `<link>` to reference to an external css file?